# How to set up a RaspberryPi(B) as a 4 year-old's PC?

Tags: operating-systems, setup

Been thinking for a while now, on how I could go about turning my RaspberryPi into a PC that my 4 year-old could play with.

I can see the (*not entirely innocent*) sparkle in his eyes when he wants to reach out and mess with my mouse and keyboard, and I think it would be great if he could start to experiment on a system where he won't accidentally harm anything.

Maybe even something where he could have some fun - like how he always wants to steal his mother's phone from her and run various videos on the Kid-Locked app she has.

I saw [Qimo](http://lifehacker.com/5182339/set-up-a-computer-for-kids-with-qimo) which looked promising, but it will not work on the ARM architecture.

Does anyone know how I might go about setting up maybe some similar solution on the Raspberry Pi?

(*As extra bonus points, if I can set up certain videos to be streamed from YouTube or from downloaded sources, without him being able to really mess it up, that would be great*)

Comment: YewToob in EU had to implement PEGI... but not sure if you can setup the account to filter adult content.

Answer (score 1):

At it's heart, Raspberry Pi is a computer and can run the things you can run on a computer (but you know that already).

For a 4 year old, look at installing the excellent gcompris software suite that will keep him entertained for days.

Start here as well

https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=49&t=104497

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Kano](http://www.kano.me/products/kano-kit). It's a complete kit which allows your child to assemble a complete (RPi-based) computer, and has a full OS tailored to children, with an activity book. Comes with all components except screen. Some reading skills required as the recommended age range is 6-12, but that's where you could assist :)

[image]

If you already have an RPi that you want to use, or if you just want to try Kano out, you can download the [Kano OS image](http://www2.kano.me/downloads) directly from their site. Of course anything using their peripherals won't work, but most of it is "normal" software. Note that their image uses an RPi2 - so it won't work on an RPi-B(+).